# How do I split this string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this string

```
(<<b>>+<<10>>)*<<c>>-(<<x>>+<<y>>)
```

Using JavaScript, what is the fastest way to parse this into

```
[b, 10, c, x, y]
```

Comment: Is the structure of the original string always the same?

Comment: I suggest reading about the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would be interesting to see more about the actual problem you're trying to solve here. It looks like you're trying to write a parsing engine? Perhaps if you expand a bit on that, you might get more answers that are actually useful rather than directly solving the sub-problem you've posed in the question currently.

Comment: Can I ask where is that string coming from, and what is the intended purpose of the angle-brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = '(<<b>>+<<10>>)*<<c>>-(<<x>>+<<y>>) ';
var arr = str.match(/<<(.*?)>>/g);
// arr will be ['<<b>>', '<<10>>', '<<c>>', '<<x>>', '<<y>>']

arr = arr.map(function (x) { return x.substring(2, x.length - 2); });
// arr will be ['b', '10', 'c', 'x', 'y']
```

Or you can also use `exec` to get the capture groups directly:

```
var regex = /<<(.*?)>>/g;
var match;
while ((match = regex.exec(str))) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

This regular expression has the benefit that you can use anything in the string, including other alphanumerical characters, without having them matched automatically. Only those tokens in `<< >>` are matched.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest:

```
"(<<b>>+<<10>>)*<<c>>-(<<x>>+<<y>>)".match(/[a-z0-9]+/g);
// ["b", "10", "c", "x", "y"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RrdRg/).

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
'(<<b>>+<<10>>)*<<c>>-(<<x>>+<<y>>)'.match(/[^(<+>)*-]+/g)
```

Comment: Or even `match(/[0-9a-z]+/g)`

Comment: how do i understand the regex inside match??can you explain..just asking??

Comment: @MESSIAH: its matching chars that are not `(<+>)*-`.

Answer (score 3):

use regex

```
var pattern=/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g
your_string.match(pattern).
```